# pass abstract parameter to requestMapping function with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, abstract-class, request-mapping

I have an abstract class **"Agent"**
and 3 other subclasses **"Developer"**, **"Support"** and **"Admin"**

Here is the code source of "Agent" :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "agents")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "role", discriminatorType = 
DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 3)

public abstract class Agent implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

private String lastName;

.........}
```

The code source of "Developer" classe

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("dev")

public class Developer extends Agent {

/*------------------- constructors -------------------*/
public Developer() {
    super();
}


public Developer(String name, String lastName, ....) {

    super(name, lastName, ...);

}
```

}

The rest of the classes "Admin", "Supprort" has the same form.

Here is my controller  code Admin controller :

```
@Controller

public class AdminController {


/*------- attributs -------*/


@Autowired
@Resource(name = "admin")
private IAdmin iAdmin;


@Autowired
private AgentValidator agentValidator;

........

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save/developer", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String createAgentAccount(Model model, String admin_id, String confirmPassword, String action, @ModelAttribute("agent") Developer developer, BindingResult result) {

    Agent admin = iAdmin.profile(Integer.parseInt(admin_id));

    developer.setConfirmPassword(confirmPassword);

    agentValidator.validate(developer, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        model.addAttribute("action", action);

        return "formAgents";

    }

    if (action.equals("create")) {

        iAdmin.createAgent(admin, developer);

    } else {

        iAdmin.updateAgent(admin, developer);

    }

    return "redirect:/admin/show/agents";

}

.......
```

As you see this function create and update the developer account, But i need to save all agents types [admin, developer, support], I try this :

```
   public String createAgentAccount(Model model, ... , @ModelAttribute("agent") Agent developer, BindingResult result) {.....}
```

But i get this error :

```
Tue Aug 22 19:54:03 WEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Failed to instantiate [com.GemCrmTickets.entities.Agent]: Is it an    abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

I know that is impossible to instanciate an abstract Class. I don't want to do a function for each type of agent, One for all will be the best solution. So i need your help please. And thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is one word. Use `Ad hoc polymorphism`, which means you can have multiple methods of `createAgentAccount`, then in each of them call an other method to handle the details.

**UPDATE**
This is what I think you want

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save/developer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAgentAccount(Model model, String admin_id, String confirmPassword, String action, @ModelAttribute("agent") Developer developer, BindingResult result) {
    return createAgentAccount(model, admin_id, confirmPassword, action, developer, result);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/save/support", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAgentAccount(Model model, String admin_id, String confirmPassword, String action, @ModelAttribute("agent") Support support, BindingResult result) {
    return createAgentAccount(model, admin_id, confirmPassword, action, support, result);
}

private String createAccount(Model model, String admin_id, String confirmPassword, String action, Agent agent, BindingResult result) {

    Agent admin = iAdmin.profile(Integer.parseInt(admin_id));

    agent.setConfirmPassword(confirmPassword);

    agentValidator.validate(agent, result);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

        model.addAttribute("action", action);

        return "formAgents";
    }

    if (action.equals("create")) {

        iAdmin.createAgent(admin, agent);

    } else {

        iAdmin.updateAgent(admin, agent);

    }

    return "redirect:/admin/show/agents";
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example please !